# Trying to use apply to make operations over different keys in a Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, keyerror

I have a Panda DataFrame that looks somewhat like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['O60829','O60341','Q9H1R3'], 'TOTAL_COVERAGE' : ['yes','yes','no'], 'BEG_D' : ['1','1','500'], 'END_D' : ['102','25','600'], 'BEG_S' : ['1','1','1'], 'END_S': ['102','25','458']})
```

And I want to iter over every row, check the value of 'TOTAL_COVERAGE' and if it's 'yes',  perform a mathematical operation over the other values, ie:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['%']  = df.apply(lambda x : ((int(x['END_S'])*100)/int(x['END_D'])) if x['TOTAL_COVERAGE'] == 'yes' else '')
```

But I'm getting the error: `KeyError: 'TOTAL_COVERAGE'`
There must be an easy fix that I'm not seeing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the column `END_M`?

Comment: Ups, it was a typo! It's was just here, not in my code

Comment: Side note: FWIW, having a % for the non-Totally Covered _stuff_ is helpful in a report. 76.33% in your case. If anything, `TOTAL_COVERAGE=yes/no` should be calculated from the % or better, from `'END_S' == 'END_D'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can solve it in a vectorized approach, no need for `iterrows` and `apply`:

```
df['%'] = (df['END_S'].astype(int) * 100 / df['END_D'].astype(int)) \
            .where(df['TOTAL_COVERAGE'] == 'yes')

df

#       ID TOTAL_COVERAGE BEG_D END_D BEG_S END_S      %
#0  O60829            yes     1   102     1   102  100.0
#1  O60341            yes     1    25     1    25  100.0
#2  Q9H1R3             no   500   600     1   458    NaN
```

---

The reason you are getting a keyError is because when you are using `apply`, the argument to lambda `x` is a column (pandas Series), which can't be used to access a specific column by it's name.

Comment: This seems to work great, and I understand the problem. Thanks! A follow-up question would be, if I use a groupby after that line, I seem to only keep the ones that have the 'yes' value and not the once with NaN. Why is this happening?

Comment: If you groupby the `%` column, I assume it's because groupby will drop nan by default. If you want to keep the `nan` rows, you can set `dropna=False` in groupby. i.e. `groupby(['%'], dropna=False)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without `iterrows` and `apply`, by equating directly:

```
df['%'] = ''
df.loc[df['TOTAL_COVERAGE'] == 'yes', '%'] = 
    df['END_S'].astype(int) * 100 / df['END_D'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do an `iterrows()`.  Conditional logic can be done with `numpy.where()` to give a far more efficient solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['O60829','O60341','Q9H1R3'], 'TOTAL_COVERAGE' : ['yes','yes','no'], 'BEG_D' : ['1','1','500'], 'END_D' : ['102','25','600'], 'BEG_S' : ['1','1','1'], 'END_S': ['102','25','458']})
df = (df
 .assign(pct=lambda x: np.where(x["TOTAL_COVERAGE"].eq("yes"),(x['END_S'].astype(int)*100)/x['END_D'].astype(int), np.nan))
 .rename(columns={"pct":"%"})
)
```

### output

```
     ID TOTAL_COVERAGE BEG_D END_D BEG_S END_S      %
 O60829            yes     1   102     1   102  100.0
 O60341            yes     1    25     1    25  100.0
 Q9H1R3             no   500   600     1   458    NaN
```